# How do I setup my web browser to default to alternate port for web development

Tags: browser, port

I would like to setup a development copy of my site on another port in order to develop it in exactly the same conditions. Is there a way to setup my browser or is there a browser capable of defaulting to another port? I'm thinking I can perhaps at least use qt's browser extension and parse the URLs, but I was wondering if there was a simpler way.

Comment: not sure how you default, and i may be being a little too simplistic, but you can just go to http://localhost:8021 (8021 being whatever port you setup)